# Get name of variable without calling it

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have `DataTable` object with test data:

```
DataTable testData = new DataTable();
```

I'd like to assign data to variables which are the same as column names. I can do it like this:

```
string foo = testData.Rows[1]["foo"].ToString();
string bar = testData.Rows[1]["bar"].ToString();
```

or:

```
string foo = testData.Rows[1][nameof(foo)].ToString();
string bar = testData.Rows[1][nameof(bar)].ToString();
```

But, I dont want to call variable name every time, I'd like to use somethink like this:

```
string foo = testData.Rows[1][nameof(this)].ToString();
string bar = testData.Rows[1][nameof(this)].ToString();
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Looks like an XY-problem for me. What is *actual* problem you're trying to solve? Why do you need to extract data to somehow named variable at all?

Comment: When any particular expression is being analyzed, the compiler doesn't take into account whether or not that particular expression happens to be on the right-hand side of an assignment operator. It certainly doesn't bring any information across as some kind of context.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, this is the best answer for my question - it is not possible and now I know why.

Comment: @Andy Korneyev you are right, I found better solution to achieve my goals, I wont use any code from my question.

Comment: Sounds do me that you need an ORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net).

Answer (score 2):

Why do you considder

```
string foo = testData.Rows[1][nameof(foo)].ToString();
```

to me more elegant than

```
string anyName = testData.Rows[1]["foo"].ToString();
```

You´d have to provide the name anyway. However variable-names don´t mean anything and are just arbitrary to be more readable.

Instead of relying on variable-names why not create a list of names and access the rows by the elements wthin that list?

```
var myList = new List<string> {"foo", "bar", ... };
```

Now you can just loop your list and get the rows value:

```
foreach(var name in myList) 
{
    var a = testData.Rows[1][name].ToString();
    // do something with a
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. My considerations was beacause I initialize variables in different ways. I will probably use Dictionary which will be the best option in my case. But mu question was can I get name of variable during assignment, and the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want a class to represent the data in the row. You could then populate an object with those properties, either using reflection or serialization. Here's a possibility using simple reflection:

```
class MyRow
{
    public string foo { get; set; }
    public string bar { get; set; }
}

var row = testData.Rows[1];
var myRow = new MyRow();
foreach (DataColumn col in testData.Columns)
{
    var prop = typeof(MyRow).GetProperty(col.ColumnName);
    prop.SetValue(myRow, (string)(row[col] ?? string.Empty), null);
}
```

You now have an object that has properties of `foo` and `bar`.

Or, using serialization instead, it looks like the `DataTable` serializes nicely into a collection of objects so you can serialize the whole table, then grab the record you want after you deserialize the table:

```
var tableJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testData);
myRow = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyRow[]>(tableJson)[1];
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. In my case I will probably use `Dictionary`. The question was about using `nameof` during assignment. And I found out it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

**loop through columns:**

```
foreach(DataColumn col in testData.Columns)
{
  var colValue = testData.Rows[1][col.ColumnName];
}
```